# Modifying GAE Django to Expand the API Scope on User Login

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics-api

In the standard django package that Google App Engine uses there is a tool for easily creating a login/logout link with this code:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
context = {
          'user':      user,
          'login':     users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),
          'logout':    users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
          }
```

My problem is that I want to make a mashup of some data using the logged in user's google analytics information. I'm sure that I can use the same login link to also request access to their analytics information, but I've not been able to figure out what I need to modify to do that.

What is it that I need to change to request that access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are using the built in [Users API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) you will have to request access to the user's analytics information using separately from the login to your app.

Alternatively you could use Google's [OpenID+OAuth Hybrid protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html), but you will not be able to use the built in Users API.  A good starting point for implementing this might be Nick Johnson's [AEoid](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/OpenID-on-App-Engine-made-easy-with-AEoid), plus the Python [OAuth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) lib.

In either case, you'll access their analytics data using the [gdata analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/).

Comment: Is it possible to modify and reinclude the built in API to be able to ask for analytics access at the same time they login?

Comment: @Robert (again), do you know of some tutorials/guides for using the google analytics api in a web application setting where there's multiple users? I've found guides and information so far about how to use it for desktop clients for single or multiple users AND how to use it in a server setting (where there's not file writing involved), but only for single users where you save your gmail user and password in plain text...

Comment: @Kort, I don't know of any good tutorials.  There shouldn't be any issues using the API in a multiuser setting. Just store the OAuth/AuthSub token on a 'user' entity you can fetch by the User's API user_id (or you're own ID if you go that route).  The key document will be the Data Export Auth docs (http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataAuthentication.html).  The usage docs (http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) look quite poor, so you're going to need to experiment (but that is very typical of gdata).  You might be best of starting with plain URLFetch.

Comment: App Engine now supports both OpenID and OAuth natively, so there's no need to use aeoid any longer.

Comment: @Nick, he is interested using "the same login link to also request access to their analytics information," which, as I understand, can not be done with the native User API or included OAuth.  You would have to authenticate via the Users API, then separately authorize again via OAuth.  Would love to find out I'm wrong though.

Comment: @Robert A separate authorization is going to be required regardless - you can't simultaneously authenticate and authorize with OAuth or anything else to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Nick, I have to admit I've not (yet) tried implementing this myself (largely because I use Users API for federated login), but you might want to have a look at: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#oauth    It is a very nice smooth process to login and approve access to resources.  Check out the demo: http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/

Comment: @Robert I'm aware of the oauth flow - but that just logs the user into the account they're authorizing and then has them authorize it. The user still has to (separately) log in to their account on the service that's consuming the API, and unless you want to have them repeat the oauth process every time, that needs to be separate.

Comment: @Nick  Login to an app that uses both federated login and gdata, then log into the hybrid demo app; you'll see the difference.  Logging in using OpenID asks you to log in, then approve access to your email, then the OAuth step will ask you to choose the account (if relevant) and finally approve access to whatever services you're requesting.  The hybrid rolls the first couple steps together, giving the user a much nicer, more streamlined, and significantly less confusing flow.  An app can store the OAuth access token as usual.